# Probability problem with deck of cards

Tags: probability

In a poker game each player is dealt five cards. What is probability that a player's hand has exactly four diamonds?

The answer is .011, I just don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $\binom{52}{5}$ $5$-card hands. They are all **equally likely**.

Now we count the hands that have exactly $4$ diamonds. The diamonds can be chosen in $\binom{13}{4}$ ways. For each of these ways, the non-diamond can be chosen in $\binom{39}{1}$ ways, for a total of $\binom{13}{4}\binom{39}{1}$.

For the probability, divide the number $\binom{13}{4}\binom{39}{1}$of "good" hands by the total number $\binom{52}{5}$ of hands.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what (13 4) looks like? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: This is the binomial coefficient, often pronounced $13$ **choose** $4$.  You may know it as $C(13,4)$, or as ${}_{13}C_4$, or as $C_4^{13}$, or ${}^{13}C_4$, and there are other notations, though most mathematicians use $\binom{13}{4}$. It is equal to $\frac{13!}{4!9!}$, which simplifies further to $\frac{(13)(12)(11)(10)}{4!}$. I think it is $715$.